# Have an initializer for android?(like Java Spring Initilizer)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Maybe someone to know, have Initializer for start project which one add Koin, Dagger, Hilt and etc in project on the start?

I tired to add all typical dependencies at the start... and decide problems with versions...

Answer (score 0):

you can reference my project https://github.com/Quangninh-io/pattern.git, i use koin, mvvm and kotlin in the project